# Can't seeing icons in bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-cardview, bottomnavigationview

I created bottom navigation inside of card View,
I can see selected icon in that but i can't see other icon in bottom navigation.
Image is here :[icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqmn5.jpg)

Comment: Please add relevant code for others to help

Comment: I will add code for that, due to slow laptop I can't send but soon as possible I will send code